# Makefile - Pass jobs param to sub makefiles

Tags: makefile, jobs

I have a makefile which calls multiple other makefiles.

I'd like to pass the -j param along to the other makefile calls.

Something like (make -j8):

```
 all:
     make -f libpng_linux.mk -j$(J)
```

Where $(J) is the value 8 from -j8. I absolutely swear I've done this before but I cannot locate my example.

$(MAKEFLAGS) seems to contain --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j regardless of what -j2 or -j8

**Edit: Possible Solution:**

Will post this as an answer soon.

It appears one solution to not worry about it.  Include -j8 when you call the main makefile.  The sub calls to make should look like this:

```
 all:
      +make -f libpng_linux.mk -j$(J)
```

Notice the "+" in front of make.  I noticed make tossing a warning when I tried parallel builds: make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.

Comment: Adding a default `-j` to a build is an "evil" thing to do.  If set low it may not have a significant impact, but if set even moderately high it can create problems in a multi-user environment.  Forcing developers to expressly choose a value forces them to make a choice -- hopefully based on how many people are on the machine, how it will impact currently running processes, etc.  With that said, the "jobserver unavailable" warning happens under 2 circumstances: gmake cannot reliably determine that the sub-process is make, or you passed -j to a submake without `+` (as you noted).

Comment: Your warning is absolutely valid and should be taken i to consideration. Now this was awhile ago but I believe  we got it so if -j is not set we default to j=1. If -j is set when calling the parent makefile it passes that j value to the children makefiles.

Answer (score 6):

[Only certain flags go into `$(MAKEFLAGS)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion).  `-j` isn't included because the sub-makes communicate with each other to ensure the appropriate number of jobs are occuring

Also, you should use `$(MAKE)` instead of `make`, since `$(MAKE)` will always evaluate to the correct executable name (which might not be `make`).

Comment: Actually, `-j` _is_ included. However, it appears only when _make_ is expanding a recipe. You won't see it for instance if you put a bare `$(info [${MAKEFLAGS}])` into the top level of your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

"Do not do that" is not always the answer, but in this case it is, at least for GNU `make`.

GNU make parent process has an internal [jobserver](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/). If top-level `Makefile` is run with `-j`, subprocess `make`s will talk to the jobserver and read a parallelism level from it, without an explicit `-j`.

Ongoing coordination with parent's jobserver is much better for core utilization. For example, during the same build with `-j6`, parent could be running 2 jobs and the child 4 more, next moment both could be running 3 jobs each, then a parent would run 1 and the child 5.